# English RTL pseudo language with gettext

Tags: wxwidgets, gettext, right-to-left

I'm trying to debug some RTL text layout issues in KiCad, which uses gettext.

There is already some support for RTL layout in wxWidgets, so when I start up with a Hebrew or Arabic locale, I get the correct widget ordering, but some of the custom widgets don't work properly as the coordinate system is also inverted.

Testing this is difficult if you don't speak a language that has RTL layout, so I'd like to generate a pseudo translation that uses strings with an Unicode RTL marker and the English text reversed.

Is there a tool that can generate this "translation", or is there a better way to test RTL layout?

Comment: The short answer is "no". You have to script it yourself.